# django-mptt children selection works on localhost but not on server

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I have the same code on localhost and on server (thanks to mercurial), but it works a little bit different. I want to render category and its subcategories in template using this code:

views.py:

```
def category(request, category_slug):
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_slug)
    except:
        raise Http404
    subcats = category.get_children()

    return render_to_response('catalogue.html',
            {'category': category,
            'subcats': subcats,
    'header_template':'common/includes/header_%s.html' % flixwood_settings.CURRENT_SITE
            },
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template:

```
<div class='subcats'>
    {% for subcat in subcats %}
    {% ifequal subcat.level 1 %}
    <div class="item">
    <a href="{% url flixwood.views.category category_slug=subcat.slug %}"><img src="{% thumbnail subcat.image 66x66 %}" class="thumb"></a>
    <a href="{% url flixwood.views.category category_slug=subcat.slug %}" class="name">{{ subcat.category }}</a>
                    {{ subcat.short_description|safe }}
    <div class="clear_left"></div>
    </div>
    {% cycle '' '' '<div class="clear_left"></div>'|safe %}
    {% endifequal %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

but however this code works perfectly on localhost (subcategories are rendering right) - it doesn't work on server, and the *{{ subcats|length }}* returns 0. 
I compared values from MySQL bases on localhost and on server - they are right and inheritance should work. The funniest thing is that the same query works perfectly in **manage.py shell** on server.

What the hack is wrong with it?

Comment: Your included code doesn't have {{subcats|length}}.  Do you mean level?

Comment: any differences in settings.py? what about the admin? any caching working here? and maybe different django versions?

Comment: {{ subcats|length }} returns 0 if I insert it at any place inside template. And there are no differences in files, it is the same repository commit. Django version also matches, it's 1.1 .

Comment: Obvious question, but are you sure the database contents are the same?  manage.py dumpdata / loaddata.  Different versions of django-mptt installed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved - it was in *.pyc* files, which are recreating only after apache is restarted. That's why the right code in *.py* files didn't work.